# Define 100 arrays, once one has been changed, the others will also be changed

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist

Now I'm ready to define many arrays, for example, 4,
code as:

```
import numpy as np
a,b,c,d = 4*[np.arange(1,11)]
a[0] = 100000
print(a)
print(b)
```

the result is shown as：

```
[10000,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
[10000,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

This means, that, the value of b will changed once a is changed. In other words, they are linked!

I'm wondering how to define many arrays with the same dimension, but their values can be changed individually. For example, in the example above, I want to show 'a' is [10000,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] and 'b' is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By `np.arange(1,11)`, you created an `arange` object. When you did `4*`, what you did is made four *identical* copies of the same object, which means when you change one, all others, because they are the same, will change as well. 
So to solve this problem, you can use `[np.arange(1,11) for _ in range(4)]`. This creates four *individual` objects with the same value.